# Convert PDF to tiff file with transparency

Tags: pdf, transparency, tiff

Is there a way to automate opening a PDF in photoshop at 2600dpi and convert to RGB then downsize the file to 360dpi. (I have to open the files at a higher resolution for gradations to look correct when first opened or the gradations don't open correctly). Lastly save the file to a .tif and keep the transparencies. I would like this to be happening from a hot folder on its own, if possible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am currently doing this by opening manually through Photoshop and using RBA for some of the steps. At the end closing and clicking through the steps to keep transparency. A real pain, but I need the transparencies in the RGB.

Answer (score 1):

Start the recording of the action before opening the files. Then follow the steps all the way through to close.

When you start the batch you will still have to confirm, by pressing OK the PDF settings which will be defaulted to 2600dpi as per your first step in the action. But it should close with the transparency saved and close the file without having to make any confirmations.

Tedious, but it might help.

Comment: You can call a script that does the settings for you so no clicking needed.

Comment: Alas, I am not versed in script.

Comment: The problem with using actions. If the next image comes in with a different proportion, it will squish the image incorrectly. I even tried image processor but that removes the transparency. If I can get a script, then I could have a hot folder run these in the background all day. Thanks everybody for your suggestions though.

Comment: @MichaelLeskow you shouldn't need to resize the image at all. Have Photoshop open the document from the folder it's in and then close it when it's done.